# RDS slow queries after few weeks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I had a problem with very slow queries in an Aurora RDS instance. In my local XAMPP the same queries took a few seconds but in RDS some of them were about 6 minutes. Trying to offer a fast solution for my customer I migrated the database from Aurora RDS to a normal MariaDB RDS instance (probably overkill but I needed to do something). After the migration query times were similar to local environment, acceptable times, but it's been three weeks since the migration and queries are very slow again, about 6 minutes.
CPU rises to almost 50% and there is only one connection in DB, the one doing the slow query.
I've checked and modified parameters in RDS but they had no visible effect in the query speed.
I've also optimized tables and at first it makes a difference but just after a few minutes the query is slow again.
I was thinking about a log table or similar which could be growing too much after three weeks and therefore slowing my queries but it's just an idea. At this point I'm a bit lost.
I'm using a db.r3.large instance with MariaDB.
Tables in these slow queries are between 63 a 200K+ rows.

Comment: You provide no information that could help people to help you. What are the slow queries? What are their execution plans? What is the memory and IO consumption of your database (this is available from CloudWatch)? What parameters did you change, and why did you think they would help?

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` at the start of your query to obtain an execution plan. Then, post it on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and ask for assistance in optimizing your query. (Hint: It's often just a matter of adding some indexes.)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306660/rds-slow-queries-after-few-weeks